# Jquery - classname alignment but not the header

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have used the JQuery datatable and for the most part I got it working. However, I am trying to apply a class but I do not want it to be applied to the header. I am confused as to how to omit the header.

```
$('#example').dataTable({
        "ajax": 'dataworks/fetchallmovements.txt',
        "order": [[0, "desc"]],
        columnDefs: [
        {type: 'date-dd-MMM-yyyy', "targets": 0},
        {className: "centre_cell", "targets": 1},
        {className: "right_cell", "targets": 2},
    ]
    });
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks. Sam

Comment: can you please share jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this instead:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "ajax": 'dataworks/fetchallmovements.txt',
    "order": [[0, "desc"]],
    columnDefs: [
    {type: 'date-dd-MMM-yyyy', "targets": 0},
    {
        "createdCell": function(cell)
        {
            $(cell).addClass('centre_cell');
        },
        "targets": 1
    },
    {
        "createdCell": function(cell)
        {
            $(cell).addClass('right_cell');
        },
        "targets": 2
    },
]
});
```